# Reflection Exception in Routes:resource

Tags: php, laravel-5

While following the steps given in the [link](https://www.flynsarmy.com/2015/02/creating-a-basic-todo-application-in-laravel-5-part-1/)

I face an error

```
[ReflectionException] Class App\Http\Controllers\postsController does not exist
```

when i run command (Mentioned under Nested Resources: Refer link)

```
php artisan route:list
```

My route.php file

```
<?php
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Application Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register all of the routes for an application.
| It's a breeze. Simply tell Laravel the URIs it should respond to
| and give it the controller to call when that URI is requested.
|
*/

Route::get('/', 'WelcomeController@index');
Route::get('contact','WelcomeController@contact');

/*Route::get('home', 'HomeController@index');

Route::controllers([
    'auth' => 'Auth\AuthController',
    'password' => 'Auth\PasswordController',
]);*/


Route::resource('posts', 'postsController');
```

[Folder Structure](http://prntscr.com/73o2mn)

( Made posts instead of Projects & Tasks)

( Skipped database seeding)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have a mistake with the file name.

the name of your Controller is postsController

```
Route::resource('posts', 'postsController');
```

but the file in your folder structure is postscontroller, make sure to rename it to postsController

Comment: Just renaming the file would suffice or is there a way to refactor the controller across whole of the app ?